# How to get dotTrace to profile memory for a web app in IIS Express 8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express, memory-profiling, dottrace

dotTrace Memory 3.5 seems to support profiling a web application using IIS or WebDev, but not IIS Express. Is this correct? If not, how do you get dotTrace to profile a 64 bit web application in IIS Express 8?

It's not an option to run the web application in WebDev40.exe.

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze memory usage of IIS Express applications using JetBrains dotMemory 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be way too late, however it is good for reference for other developers.

IIS Express is now an option since version 5.0.
https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/whatsnew/whatsnew_50.html

> Support for IIS Express 
>   As IIS Express was gaining popularity among
>   web developers, we've been receiving requests to enable profiling web
>   applications running under this server, and here we go: dotTrace 5
>   Performance introduces official support for IIS Express that
>   complements existing support for the full-fledged IIS and ASP.NET
>   Development Server.

Comment: This announce regards to the performance profiler - dotTrace. To profile memory JetBrains offers dotMemory.